# Angular custom directive doest not have any effect

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have created a custom simple directive in my angular application in this way:

```
import { Directive, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[testDirective]'
})
export class TestDirective implements OnInit {

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('directive works');
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }

}
```

I have declared it in `app.module.ts` in this way:

```
import { TestDirective } from './shared/component/tree/test.directive';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [TestDirective,...]
 ...
})
...
```

And finally here is how I'm using this directive inside my template:

```
<p testDirective>This is just for example</p>
```

I expect to see `directive works` in my browser console, and also background color of `<p>` change to red. But none of them working, and also there is not any error. Just directive does not take any effect! I don't know what's the problem. Is there any mistake in my code?

Note that my projects using version `7.2.12` of angular.

Comment: Works for me, here's the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r1a42o) for the same.

Comment: Same here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ccmrcr. My guess is that you're using this directive on a component from another module.

Comment: @NicholasK I know this is simple and expected to work, but I don't know why is not working for me and how can I fix this!

Comment: @JBNizet Yes, I'm using it from another module. Is is important?

Comment: Check if some other styles override the color after the directive changes the color.

Comment: Well, yes: if the directive is not declared nor imported in that module, components of that module can't use it: it doesn't exist in that module.

Comment: FYI: In Angular you should not touch the DOM directly via nativeElement. Instead inject the `Renderer` Service and use the provided API. Take a look here on how to use it: https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who may has same problem, as **JB Nizet** said in the comments, problem is **I'm using the directive from another module**. I moved the declaration from `app.module` to related module and it's working now.

Thanks to everybody that helped me specially **JB Nizet** for his helpful comments.